# Chi-Squared Step of Vigenere Cipher Decryption

Tags: cryptanalysis, substitution-cipher, vigenere, statistical-test

So, I have been assigned an assignment where I had to solve a Vigenere cipher.

Following along with [this webpage](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/stochastic-searching/cryptanalysis-vigenere-cipher/) I managed to get all the way to the chi-squared step. But, that is the problem. Upon trying to code this, I found my results to be unfavorable. In fact, all of my results for the chi-squared probability test for each string were exactly the same. So, obviously I did it wrong.

I tried to use the formula on [this page](http://practicalcryptography.com/cryptanalysis/text-characterisation/chi-squared-statistic/) to calculate this for each character, and for each string, I added them all together. Doing this leads to them all being the same total number for each string, which makes sense. But, if that is the case, how exactly do I use it to solve the cipher?

What I did:

- Found the key length with I.O.C. (say it's 7)
- Create a string of all the 7th characters and the 1st
- Write a method to calculate chi squared value
- Calculate this for each character in each string from A-Z
- For each string, add up the probability of all the letters(PROBLEM)

What exactly am I supposed to do here? All of my "chi-squared" results are the same.

P.S. I found the keyword using a codebreaking website to clarify that my other information was right, but I would really like how do solve this last step.